# The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 with Django Angular

Tags: django, angular, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I am using Django as backend to return API's at front end Angular side. I used AWS S3 for media storage.
URL is generating using the s3 url and able to upload the files on S3 bucket. Problem is on web the Image content getting the 400 Bad Request.
following is my code:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "app"

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
#AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH=False
```

when I am uncommenting the #AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH=False and making all the s3 Images as public then able to access the image on web, need to make image explicitly public, which I don't want this.
after commention getting the url like -

```
https://famesta-app.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/user_30/profile/download.png?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&Signature=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx%3D&Expires=1592369615
```

**Error:**

```
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
    <Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message>
    <RequestId>20DF944878611</RequestId>
    <HostId>sZPyWKvGHSRt7ANyDlOUh71/xUV14H0avAjaERfkoQxiq0=</HostId>
</Error>
```

My region is **Asia Pacific (Mumbai)**

**AWS Configuration-**

CORS Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

And In S3 Permission I have allow the Public access.
If I will make whole bucket as public and AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH=False then able to upload image get access on web everything that I wanted, but I don't think so it is safe to make bucket itself public.
Please help me.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591989/amazon-web-services-s3-the-authorization-mechanism-you-have-provided-is-not-s) help?

Comment: @MatthewHegarty I tried , but didin't help, may be it's issue with my India(Mumbai) region?

Comment: Possibly.  I can only suggest googling and reading around as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

For India People, provide the region name in settings.py file it's mandatory, as you can see in the library it's picking up from settings default value not provided

```
region_name = setting('AWS_S3_REGION_NAME')
```

so use the key-value pair as

```
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'ap-south-1'
```

Answer (score 0):

For Asia Pacific (Mumbai) Region, add the below to your `settings.py` file

```
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'ap-south-1'

AWS_S3_ADDRESSING_STYLE = "virtual"
```